# Safari extension to check if you're currently logged-in to Google/Facebook/etc.?

Tags: safari, gmail

Is there a Safari extension anywhere that shows a banner (or something equivalent) whenever you're logged-in to Google/Facebook/etc.?

I *rarely* sign into Gmail from the web, and when I do I want to make sure I sign out as soon as I'm finished doing whatever I'm doing. I often forget though, and only notice days later that I've been logged in that whole time.

An extension that gives a clear "warning" when you're logged-in would be fantastic, and solve my problem, but my searches thus far have turned up nothing.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to have such an extension? I don't know of an extension, but maybe there is another solution to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: I don't like the idea of Google (or anyone) tracking my web-browsing history simply because I forgot to log out of their service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an extension that will warn you about remaining logged into Facebook or Google accounts. However, since your goal is to block web trackers from services like these, a better solution is to install an extension that blocks web tracking bugs. I personally use and recommend [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/). Ghostery works with Safari, plus Chrome, Firefox and IE, and it blocks Facebook and Google trackers, plus a slew of others as well. With a plugin like this you can also safely remain logged into your Google and Facebook accounts as well.

Comment: Interesting. I think I'll run this either way, it seems like a good idea. But this won't block Google from tracking my search results, right?

Comment: This will not stop Google from tracking your search results when you do a web search from Google.com, but it will stop their ad network from tracking you around the web. However, Google can technically track your search results whether or not you're logged in, it's just a matter of whether they link it to an account or an IP address. You can also disable your Google Search History Personalization, but this isn't quite perfect either: http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54048